# How can I filter folder directories by a certain variable using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to randomly select a folder inside a directory possibly using `random.choice()` (or any). But it is actually not that random. It has to filter first the folders (inside that directory) based on a condition or variable and then randomly select a folder from that list

Example:
list of folders inside the directory are:

`peter_folder1`, `peter_folder2`, `peter_folder3`, `denise_folder1`, `denise_folder2`, `mark_folder1`, `mark_folder2`

I want to randomly select a folder from `peter`, or from `denise`, or from `mark`. If I choose `peter`, it has to randomly select a folder from the list of `peter_folder1`, `peter_folder2`, `peter_folder3`. If from `denise`, `denise_folder1`, `denise_folder2` and etc.

So far, I have only filtered the folders to return a list

```
os.chdir(folder_path)
sorted_folders = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(folder_path)
print(sorted_folders)
```

Comment: "randomly select a folder from peter, or from denise, or from mark" What do you mean by this?  Are peter / denise / mark actual folders?  You didn't list those in the example.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html can do exactly that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is filer `sorted_folders` for ones start with the intended name. From there, you can then simply run `random.choice()` on the resulting list. Rather than using another `filer()` call with a lambda and then converting the result to a list, I chose to use a list comprehension, however, both work fine:

```
os.chdir(folder_path)
sorted_folders = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir())

name = input('Enter a filter name: ')
filtered = [folder for folder in sorted_folders if folder.startswith(name)]
random_folder = random.choice(filtered)
print(random_folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this:

```
import random

sorted_folders = ["peter_folder1", "peter_folder2", "peter_folder3", "denise_folder1", "denise_folder2", "mark_folder1", "mark_folder2"]

names = list(set(folder.split("_")[0] for folder in sorted_folders))
name = random.choice(names)

folders = [folder for folder in sorted_folders if folder.startswith(name)]
folder = random.choice(folders)

print(folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a standard naming convention, e.g., name separated by an underscore.

This randomly selects a name, peter, denise, or mark, though that part could also be manual. Then it randomly selects a folder from that person.

```
$ cat filter.py 
import os
from secrets import choice, randbelow

folder_path='.'

os.chdir(folder_path)
sorted_folders = [name for name in os.listdir() if os.path.isdir(name) \
                                                      and '_' in name]
print(sorted_folders)
choices = {name.split('_')[0]:[] for name in sorted_folders}
print(choices)
for name in sorted_folders:
  choices[name.split('_')[0]].append(name)
print(choices)

while len(choices) > 0:
  name = choice(list(choices.keys()))
  choiceindex = randbelow(len(choices[name]))
  folder = choices[name][choiceindex]
  del choices[name][choiceindex]
  if len(choices[name]) == 0:
    del choices[name]
  print(f'Chose {folder}')
```

Gives the output:

```
$ python filter.py 
['peter_folder1', 'denise_folder2', 'peter_folder3', 'mark_folder1', 'mark_folder2', 'denise_folder1', 'peter_folder2']
{'peter': [], 'denise': [], 'mark': []}
{'peter': ['peter_folder1', 'peter_folder3', 'peter_folder2'], 'denise': ['denise_folder2', 'denise_folder1'], 'mark': ['mark_folder1', 'mark_folder2']}
Chose denise_folder2
Chose peter_folder3
Chose denise_folder1
Chose mark_folder2
Chose mark_folder1
Chose peter_folder2
Chose peter_folder1
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with files in Python, a good alternative is to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). If you're using python 3.11, your entire example becomes:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import random

folder = Path(folder_path)
sorted_folders = list(folder.glob("peter*/")) # Select all folders that start with peter...

random_folder = random.choice(sorted_folders)
```

Just remember that now you're dealing with `Path` objects instead of strings.

```py
type(random_folder) # PosixPath or WindowsPath
str(random_folder) # peter_folder2
```